# How can I get all possible "leet" versions of a string (with optional substitutions)?

Tags: python, python-itertools, cartesian-product

I wrote a straightforward function that converts letters in words to their 'leet' numerical counterparts.

```
def Leet(word):
    letters = list(word.lower())
    for n, letter, in enumerate(letters):
        if letter == 'o':
            letters[n]= '0'
        elif letter == 'i':
            letters[n]= '1'
        elif letter == 'z':
            letters[n]= '2'
        elif letter == 'e':
            letters[n]= '3'
        elif letter == 'a':
            letters[n]= '4'
        elif letter == 's':
            letters[n]= '5'
        elif letter == 'g':
            letters[n]= '6'
        elif letter == 't':
            letters[n]= '7'
        elif letter == 'b':
            letters[n]= '8'
    return ''.join(letters)
```

so when I input `'zit'`, the program will return `'217'`.

My question is, how can I change it to give me every possible result (`'217'`, `'2it'`, `'z1t'`, `'zi7'`, `'21t'`, etc.)? I've read about `itertools` but I am stumped as to how to apply it to my function.

Comment: Note that a dictionary `{'o': '0', ...}` would make this **much** neater.

Comment: As asked, this is too broad. There are two separate questions: 1) how do I figure out the candidates for each position in the output string? 2) How do I get the Cartesian product of those candidate sets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First observation is that you can shorten the lookup, like this:

```
REPLACE = { letter: str(index) for index, letter in enumerate('oizeasgtb') }

def Leet2(word):
    letters = [ REPLACE.get(l, l) for l in word.lower() ]
    return ''.join(letters)
```

`REPLACE` looks like:

```
{'a': '4', 'b': '8', 'e': '3', 'g': '6', 'i': '1', 
 'o': '0', 's': '5', 't': '7', 'z': '2'}
```

And the `REPLACE.get(l,l)` gives you back either the replacement letter, or the original letter if there is no replacement.

The second observation is that you don't really want permutations, which are shifts in ordering. The permutations of '217' are:

```
>>> [ ''.join(p) for p in permutations('217') ]
['217', '271', '127', '172', '721', '712']
```

What you really need is the product of a list that encodes all the possible choices for a given character position:

```
[('z', '2'), ('i', '1'), ('t', '7')]
```

How this works might be clearer if I also show a possibility list with some characters for which there is no valid replacement. For `'red'` for example:

```
[('r',), ('e', '3'), ('d',)]
```

Now we need the string-joined product of those options. Putting it all together:

```
from itertools import product

def Leet2Combos(word):
    possibles = []
    for l in word.lower():
        ll = REPLACE.get(l, l)
        possibles.append( (l,) if ll == l else (l, ll) )
    return [ ''.join(t) for t in product(*possibles) ]

print Leet2Combos('zit')
print Leet2Combos('red')
```

Gives:

```
['zit', 'zi7', 'z1t', 'z17', '2it', '2i7', '21t', '217']
['red', 'r3d']
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). Also, I would suggest using a `dict` for the mapping instead of a cascade of `if/elif`.

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> LEET = { 'z': '2', 'i': '1', 't': '7' } # and all the others     
>>> word = "zit"
>>> [''.join(letters) for letters in product(*({c, LEET.get(c, c)} for c in word))]
['zit', 'zi7', 'z1t', 'z17', '2it', '2i7', '21t', '217']
```

Note that `LEET.get(c, c)` will get the "leet" letter from the dict, or use the original letter as a default. The `{...}` is used to make those pairs sets, so there are no duplicates for letters with no replacement. In older versions of Python, you might have to use `set([...])` instead.

That rather complex `product(*...)` line works roughly like this:

```
    product(*({c, LEET.get(c, c)} for c in 'zit'))
==> product(*({'z', LEET.get('z', 'z')}, {'i', LEET.get('i', 'i')}, {'t', LEET.get('t', 't')}))
==> product(*({'z', '2'}, {'i', '1'}, {'t', '7'}))
==> product(  {'z', '2'}, {'i', '1'}, {'t', '7'} )
```

which produces the [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of all those letters and their replacements.

Comment: Nice answer. I wonder what's with the `*`, in `product(*[(...`? I'm not 100% comfortable with Python yet.

Comment: This works great for words like `'zit'` for which there are two choices for every letter position. It works slightly less well for words like `'red'`, for which it returns `['red', 'red', 'r3d', 'r3d', 'red', 'red', 'r3d', 'r3d']`--a list with duplicates. Suggest wrapping either the result or the internal list tuples with a `set()` operation to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), as you mentionned, which will perform a cartesian product of a list.

The problem will be to have this list, of every combinaison e.g for zit the list should be:

```
[['z', '2'], ['i', '1'], ['t', '7']]
```

My code:

```
import itertools

def leet(word):
    leet_matches = [['a', '4'],
    ['b' ,'8'],
    ['c'],
    ['d'],
    ['e', '3'],
    ['f'],
    ['g', '6'],
    ['h'],
    ['i', '1'],
    ['j'],
    ['k'],
    ['l'],
    ['m'],
    ['n'],
    ['o', '0'],
    ['p'],
    ['q'],
    ['r'],
    ['s', '5'],
    ['t', '7'],
    ['u'],
    ['v'],
    ['w'],
    ['x'],
    ['y'],
    ['z', '2']]
    l = []
    for letter in word:
        for match in leet_matches:
            if match[0] == letter:
                l.append(match)
    return list(itertools.product(*l))

print leet("zit")
```

Note that using list of list (or tuples) instead of Dict allows you to have several replacements for one letter, e.g. "i" can become "1" or "!"