# Is there a way to replace letters with numbers/symbols in JS and show each possible outcome?

Tags: javascript, string, combinations

I am working on a project where I need to covert a list of words into all possible options using symbols / numbers.

I actually want functionality pretty much identical to [This Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29151145/leet-program-getting-all-permutations), however, it is written in Python using the intertools.product method. I do not know how to convert this into JS.

For example:

```
let givenInput= 'hello';
let expectedOutput = ["hello", "h3llo", "he1lo", "hel1o", "hell0", "h31lo", "h3l1o", "h3ll0", "he11o", "he1l0", "hel10", "h311o", "h31l0", "h3l10", "he110", "h3110"];
```

I tried having an object with the replacements I am expecting:

```
let REPLACE = {
'o': '0',
'e': '3',
'l': '1',
'a': '@'
}
```

I have tried a more manual method, where I replace one letter, add that option to an array, change another, add that to the array, etc. But I need to know too much about the string I am manipulating.

I have also tried to just use `string.replace()` using a regex, but that only really seems to work when I am replacing ALL of one character with another one and not one at a time.

The end goal of this is a generator to generate a list of words I do not want to be allowed in a name creator. So like, I want to exclude bad words, and all possible letter-replacement versions of those words.

Comment: Your end goal would be easier to reach with a regular expression, which for your example could be `h[e3][1l][1l][o0]`. And then you can test a user submitted name against it.

Comment: "I want to exclude bad words" [Good luck with that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).

Comment: @JaredSmith [clbuttic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clbuttic)!

Comment: What is actually wrong with someone choosing an alphanumeric name?

Comment: @trincot I thought about that, but I think that will only work if I know every word. I am looking more for a function that based on an object or something, can automatically create a list of words with different permutations. I think this is easily solved if I have one word, but I am actually dealing with a few hundred words. The end goal is to generate a TXT with a comma separated list of words.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Nothing! I am more worried about letting people use names with slurs or something in them.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular imagine the horror of somebody using "5hits"

Comment: @Russ [Like Michael Cock](https://twitter.com/matthewcock/status/89431901651222528)? Craig **Cock**burn? Linda C**allah**an? Dr. Herman I. Lib**shit**z? Benedict **Cum**berbatch? Dick Van Dyke? Tyson Gay? These are all names of real people that *have* been blocked or censored in various places because of overzealous filters.

Comment: @Russ, if you are actually dealing with a few hundred words, then you can generate a regular expression for them dynamically.

Comment: How about heⅼⅼo or h̸̛̖͝e̶̞̎͗l̷̛͚l̴̖̀͋o̶̥͂̒. How will you avoid that?

Comment: @Russ just in case it's not clear from the lengthly lists of linked counter examples, **give up**. You *may*, and I stress this, *may* want to flag names for human review, but be very, very careful. Programmers often get accused of arrogance, and when it comes to names [this is for once completely justified](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Answer (score 1):

You could build an array of replacement characters and get the cartesian product.

```js
const
    input= 'hello',
    REPLACE = { o: '0', e: '3', l: '1', a: '@' },
    result = Array
        .from(input, c => c in REPLACE ? [c, REPLACE[c]] : [c])
        .reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []))
        .map(a => a.join(''));
        
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for what I was trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

Imagine this approach:

1. Take the first letter of the input. Either it can or can't be substituted. This creates a list of options for the first letter which contains either one or two elements (either the letter alone, or the letter along with its substitution)
2. Take all the letters beyond the first letter, and get their permutations (in other words, solve this problem for all letters beyond the 1st)
3. If the options for the first letter includes just one option, simply prepend that character to each result in the list of permutations for the letters beyond the first (and you're done!) If there are *two* options for the first letter return the list of beyond-the-first-letter-permutations *doubled*; but for every item in the first half of that list prepend the first initial-letter-option, and for every item in the second half prepend the second initial-letter option.

It may seem magical that this solution *requires itself to already be defined* (in step #2), but this is no problem for many programming languages.

Here we'll define `permuteSubstitutions(str, subs)` as the function which solves this problem. Now as we're implementing the full solution we can gloss over step #2 by simply referring to `permuteSubtitutions`.

```js
let permuteSubstitutions = function*(str, subs) {
  
  // There's only one possible permutation for the empty string
  if (!str) { yield ''; return; }
  
  // Either 1 or 2 options for the head:
  // - Only the leading character, if it can't be substituted,
  // - or the leading character and substituted character
  let heads = subs.hasOwnProperty(str[0])
    ? [ str[0], subs[str[0]] ]
    : [ str[0] ];
  
  // `str`, minus its first letter
  let tail = str.slice(1);
  
  // For each possible leading letter yield a result for each permutation
  // of the tailing letters. This works because of the definition we gave
  // to `permuteSubstitutions`! We'll get every permutation of the `tail`,
  // and combine it with the possibilities for `head`.
  for (let permutedTail of permuteSubstitutions(tail, subs)) {
    for (let head of heads) {  
      yield head + permutedTail;
    }
  }
  
};

let results = permuteSubstitutions('hello', {
  'o': '0',
  'e': '3',
  'l': '1',
  'a': '@'
});
for (let result of results) console.log(result);
```

You may have noticed that every substitutable letter *doubles* the number of resulting permutations. For that reason I've implemented this for you as a [function*(...){...}](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator), which will have no issue returning a vast number of results (unlike a buffered/Array-based approach). You should still be careful with this code, as if someone manages to get your code to verify the term `oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo` your cpu may wind up performing 2^100 iterations, and that will make it quite sad.

Note that if you are trying to detect terms that may contain homoglyphs you will have much more success "normalizing" words and directly comparing them against your dictionary. Just replace all "homoglyphic" letters with their base meaning (e.g. transform `4 -> A`, `@ -> A`, `1 -> L`, `3 -> E`, etc.) This would transform a string like:

```
1@NGU4G3
```

into:

```
LANGUAGE
```

allowing the word to be directly compared to a dictionary. This overall will have a *much* more reasonable runtime.

Comment: Thank you! this solution made a lot of sense to me. I actually never thought of going the other way. I think that would actually make a little more sense to normalize the words and turn them into regular English. Thank you!